# Incorrect Height When Setting UITextView Height Inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview

I am trying to set the height of a UITextView so that it fits all the text within the view without scrolling. Autolayout seems to be working because it adjusts the size in every instance, the problem is however that it never quite gets the correct height. There always seems to be a chunk missing from the bottom.

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"VideoContentCell";

    VideoContentTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[VideoContentTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    /// ----------
    /// Setup the video title
    /// ----------

    [cell.videoTitle setText:[self.videoObject.videoTitle capitalizedString]];


    /// ----------
    /// Setup the channel image
    /// ----------

    [cell.imageChannel.layer setCornerRadius:15.f];

    if(self.videoObject.videoPublisherThumbnail != (id)[NSNull null]){
        [cell.imageChannel sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.videoObject.videoPublisherThumbnail]
                                 placeholderImage:nil];
    }


    /// ----------
    /// Setup the channel title
    /// ----------

    [cell.channelInfo setText:[self.videoObject.videoPublisher capitalizedString]];


    /// ----------
    /// Setup the video description
    /// ----------

    [cell.videoInfo   setText:self.videoObject.videoDescription];

    CGSize sizeThatFitsTextView = [cell.videoInfo sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(cell.videoInfo.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];


    //Height to be fixed for SubView same as AdHeight
    NSLayoutConstraint *height = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:cell.videoInfo
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:nil
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                  multiplier:0
                                  constant:sizeThatFitsTextView.height];

    [cell.videoInfo addConstraint:height];

    [cell.videoInfo setNeedsUpdateConstraints];




    return cell;

}
```

Comment: You need to set height for cell as well as per the height of textview. 
.
.

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{}

.
.
method

Comment: The UITextView has a constraint set to the bottom of the UITableViewCell so it is adjusting in height dynamically.

Comment: have you disable scrolling in the textview? Also try call layoutIfNeeded

Comment: Yep tried both but no luck, the text view does resize based on the content. It just seems to be missing a chunk from the bottom each time.

Comment: @ORStudios Have you enabled auto layout for UITableview. `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0; // set to whatever your "average" cell height is`

Comment: Yep done that as well, as mentioned the autolayout seems to work the only thing I can think of is that sizeThatFits is bringing back the wrong values for height.

Comment: Ok If I ditch the height constraint and use the following then the text view displays the content correctly. [cell.videoInfo setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.videoInfo.frame.origin.x, cell.videoInfo.frame.origin.y, cell.videoInfo.frame.size.width, sizeThatFitsTextView.height)]; It must be something to do with with the height constraint.

Comment: Found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `layoutIfNeeded` method

```
[cell.videoInfo addConstraint:height];

 [cell.videoInfo setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

[self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // call this method
```